# Using android beacon library to get the application running in the background

Tags: android, ibeacon-android

I'm using the android beacon library to get the application running in the background to let the application scan for ibeacons even the user goes to the task switcher and swipes an app off the screen.
the beacon library is here : 
https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/index.html

the code i used:
**MonitoringActivity** for searching for ibeacons :

```
  public MonitoringActivity() {

}


private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;
private BeaconManager beaconManager;
private BackgroundPowerSaver backgroundPowerSaver;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d("Beacon app", "App started up");

    // wake up the app when any beacon is seen (you can specify specific id filers in the parameters below)
    Region region = new Region("UniqueId", null, null, null);
    regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);

    //Changing between scan periode
    backgroundPowerSaver= new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);
    //beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(5000l);
    //beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(10000l);



}


@Override
public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int arg0, Region arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void didEnterRegion(Region arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Log.v("Beacon entry ", "beacon entred to range");
    Intent intent = new Intent(MonitoringActivity.this, MonitoringActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

**RangActivity**for result:

```
  public class RangActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rang);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.rang, menu);
    return true;
}
```

and the code of the manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />

<application
    android:name=".MonitoringActivity"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:persistent="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MonitoringActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_monitoring" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RangActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_rang"

         >
    </activity>
</application>
```

the problem that i have that the application works only whene i press tha back button until it exit or the home button but if i goes to the task switcher and swipes the app off the screen it's not running anymore . How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Killing an app from the task switcher will shut down the app so it is not running, preventing it from detecting beacons (at least for awhile).  The library is designed to re-launch itself on the next power connect/disconnect event.  So for testing purposes, simply connect your phone to a charger or to your computer's USB port.

You can read more about this limitation here:  http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/resume-after-terminate.html

**EDIT:  On some devices, folks have reported that the ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED event does not work after killing apps with the task switcher.** You can see a discussion of the issue here: https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/44

I have created a test app [here](https://github.com/davidgyoung/power-connect-tester) to see if this issue applies to your specific device.  If you can install that test app on your device and follow the instructions, you should know if you device is affected.  Please report back your results!

Comment: that's what i'm doing but still not result if i kill the app

Comment: You are saying it does not detect beacons if you connect the mobile device to a charger?  Can you please post your mobile device make, model and OS version?

Comment: i m using Galaxy Grand Prime 4.4.4 . the problem is that when i disconnect the device it runs for the first time but if i kill the app again it doesn't work anymore